# Inserção no banco de dados através de Webservice

Tags: java, web-service, postgresql

Boa noite,

Sei muito pouco sobre `Webservice`. E, por meio de tutoriais, eu consegui criar um. O conteúdo foi retirado deste site: 
[Criando Web-*Service*](http://www.dainf.ct.utfpr.edu.br/~caio/ws/ProjetoCriandoWS.pdf)

A consulta é feita com sucesso, mas agora eu preciso que na página do `Webservice`, o usuário digite algumas informações, e estas informações sejam inseridas no banco de dados `Postgres`.

Como faço? É possível? Preciso utilizar alguma outra tecnologia?

Estou perdida :/

Comment: Poste algum código do seu webservice de busca (editando a pergunta para fazer isso). Assim é possível saber-se melhor como é que você está obtendo os parâmetros do seu serviço, acessando o banco de dados e exibindo os resultados. Também fica mais fácil para servidr de base para elaborar uma boa resposta que seja compatível com o resto do seu projeto.

Comment: A forma mais simples de criar um WS em Java, na minha opinião é usando o JAX-WS, observe que você escreve código Java, e utiliza annotations. Veja estes links: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3654/desenvolvendo-e-usando-web-services-em-java.aspx e http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/

Comment: Você precisa de uma página para o usuário entrar com dados, com os serviços do webservice não acredito que seja possivel criar uma página de cadastro, e se for não vai ser a melhor forma de se fazer, o melhor a fazer é criar uma página usando jsf, pesquise um pouco sobre jsf. E no mesmo projeto vc consegue fazer isso.

Answer (score 2):

Eu vejo que você precisa ter um sólido conhecimento do que exatamente é um Web Service, quais são seus propósitos.

Notei que você quer saber maneiras de fazer com que a "página do Web Service" permite que o usuário digite informações e você venha a cadastrar os dados.

Não existe a **Página do Web Service.**

**Existem Operações nos Web Service.**

No caso, o que você quer é *adicionar* uma nova operação que permita que um cliente/consumidor(que sim, pode ser uma aplicação que forneça uma interface para um usuário digitar) do seu serviço adicione novas informações.

Recomendo que você tenha um sólido entendimento do que é um Web Service.

Aqui estão alguns links para começar:

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijvh.html
(este último da Oracle tem excelentes explicações)

Quanto sua pergunta efetivamente - Adicione este método/operação na mesma classe que implementa o WebService

@WebMethod(operationName = "adicionarMunicipio")
public String buscaMunicipio(@WebParam(name = "municipio") String municipio) {
   //Demais lógica acessando métodos para inserir no Banco de Daddos
}

Faça o deploy novamente do seu WebService e este serviço já estará disponível.

Para o consumo, se quiser escrever um cliente em Java, utilize o utilitário *wsimport*

http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-wsimport-tool-example/

Esse é um assunto extenso e rico em detalhes, dificilmente vc poderá aprender tudo apenas com minha resposta, portanto, estude mais, não apenas siga tutoriais, eles são importantes, mas entenda os propósitos por traz.

Answer (score 0):

Você terá que criar um cliente para um Web Service, o NetBeans irá te ajudar, assim, siga o link abaixo:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client_pt_BR.html

Depois criar o cliente, implemente alguma interface Web (Servlet ou JSP) para utilizar o cliente